# GridBagLayout to enforce component sizing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to use gridbaglayout to layout components within a panel. I used graph paper to try to get the scaling correct, and used that to help determine the weightx/weighty/gridx/gridy values.

My JPanel size (on paper) is 8 x 18. I then added a JButton as follows:

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc.height=2;
gbc.width=6;
gbc.gridx=1;
gbc.gridy=1;
gbc.weightx =.75;
gbc.weighty = .11;
add(new JButton(), gbc);
```

The JButton takes up the entire JPanel. Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height. 3) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: I tried to upload an image, but I'm not seeing it. Are .bmp images supported?

Comment: *"upload an image"*  Minor point, but nobody suggested you post an image.  OTOH, I did specify *"and (if resizable) with extra width/height"*.  Is it resizable?  Don't presume we can read your mind.  Although our powers are extensive, they do not go *that far.*

Comment: As an aside.  Why did you destroy the edits I made?  That is quite irritating.  :-/  Use the [Edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20569188/edit) on the page, rather than the 'back button' to edit a question!

Comment: My mistake. How can I create the GUI in ASCII art form

Comment: *"How can I.."*  What don't you understand about it?  Now would be a good time for more words, rather than less.  But be sure to do a Google search on the term first.

Comment: I went back and edited my question to try to make my problem explanation simpler, just the necessary parts.

Comment: `just the necessary parts.` 10 lines of code doesn't help us. We need to know the context of how this code is used with your other components that you add to the panel. You have been asked to post a `SSCCE`.

Comment: I got it figured out, thanks to all.